# Filtering an object based on an parent key in the object (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

### Unfiltered Object

I have this JSON object:

```
  items = [
    {id: 1, name: "home",  parent: 0, active: 1,  order: 0},
    {id: 2, name: "dashboard", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1},
    {id: 3, name: "report1",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11},
    {id: 4, name: "analytics", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 2},
    {id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21},
    {id: 6, name: "report3",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22},
    {id: 7, name: "analytics_page1",  parent: 4, active: 1, order: 23}
    
  ]
```

### Object I want

I want to filter it by parent, keeping any with a parent number of 0, and moving any values with a parent number that matches the id into its children. So I want something like this:

```
  itemsUpdated= [
    { id: 1, 
      name: "home",  
      parent: 0, 
      active: 1,  
      order: 0, 
      children:[]
    },
    { id: 2, 
      name: "dashboard", 
      parent: 0, 
      active: 1, 
      order: 1, 
      children:[
         {id: 3, name: "report1",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11, children: []},
         {id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21, children:[]},
         {id: 6, name: "report3",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22, children:[]}
      ]
    },
    { id: 4, 
      name: "analytics", 
      parent: 0, 
      active: 1, 
      order: 2, 
      children:[
         {id: 7, name: "analytics_page1",  parent: 4, active: 1, order: 23, children:[]}
      ]
    }
  ]
```

### My Approach

so far I have managed to add a children key with an empty array to every item:

```
 let itemsUpdated = items;
    for(let i = 0 ; i < itemsUpdated .length; i++){
      itemsUpdated [i].children = [];
    }

//MY UPDATED ITEMS LOOKS LIKE THIS 
 updatedItems = [
    {id: 1, name: "home",  parent: 0, active: 1,  order: 0, children:[]},
    {id: 2, name: "dashboard", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1, children:[]},
    {id: 3, name: "report1",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11, children:[]},
    {id: 4, name: "analytics", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 2, children:[]},
    {id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21, children:[]},
    {id: 6, name: "report3",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22, children:[]},
    {id: 7, name: "analytics_page1",  parent: 4, active: 1, order: 23, children:[]}

  ]
```

How would I go about filtering and reducing this array down ?

Comment: One question.. according to your logic, there are **3** `Objects` with the `parent` attribute/key with the value of `2`. Why are there **ONLY 2** children in the object with id `2`?

Comment: Im sorry I misswrote - I'll fix it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case for [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), accumulating each object into the `children` array of its parent indexed by `id` in the accumulator object. The result is the array stored in the `['0']` property of the returned object.

The advantage of this over some of the other approaches is that it doesn't employ nested loops.

*(items array edited from question to include nested children: `id: 7` is a child of `id: 6`)*

```js
const items = [
  { id: 3, name: "report1", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11 },
  { id: 1, name: "home", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "dashboard", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: "analytics", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21 },
  { id: 6, name: "report3", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22 },
  { id: 7, name: "analytics_page1", parent: 6, active: 1, order: 23 }
]

const result = items.reduce((a, o) => {
  a[o.id] = a[o.id] || [];
  a[o.parent] = a[o.parent] || [];

  a[o.parent].push({ ...o, children: a[o.id] });

  return a;
}, {})['0'];

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A little more concise using [logical nullish assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

```js
const items = [
  { id: 3, name: "report1", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11 },
  { id: 1, name: "home", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "dashboard", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1 },
  { id: 4, name: "analytics", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21 },
  { id: 6, name: "report3", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22 },
  { id: 7, name: "analytics_page1", parent: 6, active: 1, order: 23 }
]

const result = items
  .reduce((a, o) => (
    (a[o.parent] ??= []).push({ ...o, children: (a[o.id] ??= []) }), a), {}
  )['0'];

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'home', parent: 0, active: 1, order: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: 'dashboard', parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1 },
    { id: 3, name: 'report1', parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11 },
    { id: 4, name: 'analytics', parent: 0, active: 1, order: 2 },
    { id: 5, name: 'report2', parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21 },
    { id: 6, name: 'report3', parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22 },
    { id: 7, name: 'analytics_page1', parent: 4, active: 1, order: 23 }
  ];

  const itemsUpdated = items
    .filter(el => !el.parent)
    .map((el, idx) => {
      el.children = [];
      items.forEach(e => {
        if (e.parent === idx+1) {
          el.children.push(e);
        }
      });
      return el;
    });

console.log(itemsUpdated);
```

Comment: almost.. the linking links up the wrong things though :{\

Answer (score 0):

ik, ik, im the latest to answer but this was a really fun question :D

```js
let items = [
  {id: 1, name: "home",  parent: 0, active: 1,  order: 0},
  {id: 2, name: "dashboard", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1},
  {id: 3, name: "report1",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11},
  {id: 4, name: "analytics", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 2},
  {id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21},
  {id: 6, name: "report3",  parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22},
  {id: 7, name: "analytics_page1",  parent: 4, active: 1, order: 23}
]
//I assume you wont want the original items(since with reference logic.. some editing to this will be done)
let itemsUpdated = items //turn this line into 'let itemsUpdated = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items))' if you don't want items edited
//firstly a finder function to return elements which parents match an id n
function findMatches(n){
  let arr=[]
  itemsUpdated.forEach(a=>{if(a.parent==n){arr.push(a)}})
  return arr
}
//now to link >:D
itemsUpdated.forEach(a=>{
  a.children=[] //your for loop's equivalent :D
  let matches=findMatches(a.id)
  if(matches.length){
    matches.forEach(b=>{a.children.push(b)})
  }
})
//now to filter as the finishing touch
itemsUpdated=itemsUpdated.filter(a=>a.parent==0)
console.log(itemsUpdated)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also want to submit my trial with recursion in mind for nested children, you can see the example of id: 4

```
let items = [
  { id: 1, name: "home", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "dashboard", parent: 0, active: 1, order: 1 },
  { id: 3, name: "report1", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 11 },
  { id: 4, name: "analytics", parent: 3, active: 1, order: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: "report2", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 21 },
  { id: 6, name: "report3", parent: 2, active: 1, order: 22 },
  { id: 7, name: "analytics_page1", parent: 4, active: 1, order: 23 }
];

//adds children empty array
items.forEach((item) => {
  item.children = [];
  return item;
});

//filters parents on 0 level first
let newItems = items.filter((item) => item.parent === 0);

//recursion
items.forEach((item) => searchParent(newItems, item));

console.log(newItems);

function searchParent(someArray, childObject) {
  someArray.forEach((parent) => {
    if (parent.id === childObject.parent) {
      parent.children.push(childObject);
    } else {
      if (parent.children) searchParent(parent.children, childObject);
    }
  });
}
```